Observable state of a program
I came across the following excerpt on page 46 of Modern C by Jens Gustedt, and would like to clarify my understanding of the second sentence (highlighted in bold):

For an optimization to be valid, it is only important that a C compiler produces an executable that reproduces the observable statesC. Observable states consist of the contents of some variables (and similar entities that we will see later) and the output as they evolve during the execution of the program. This whole mechanism of change is called the abstract state machineC.

What exactly are the phrases "some variables" and "the output" referring to? My initial guess was that "some variables" meant objects whose values are used in output operations, e.g. the x and y in printf("%d", x*y), and that "the output" meant program output (i.e. from operations that output the value of objects, e.g. printf("%d", x*y), as well as those that output the value of expressions containing only literals, e.g. printf("%d", 100*2)). But I'm not sure if this is correct, since this interpretation seems to make the phrase "some variables" redundant.
The C Standard does not use the term "observable state", but does define something called observable behaviour in §5.1.2.4(6), which includes "volatile accesses". So now I'm wondering if the phrase "some variables" is referring to objects that are volatile-accessed?
Also, what are the "similar entities" that the excerpt alludes to? The only other use of the term "observable state" occurs in §5.1.4 on page 47, but that section does not introduce any new entities.

You need to read (4) in conjunction with (6). The compiler is free to produce code that behaves "as if" it was a verbatim compilation of the source, even though the compiler may optimize out variables or functions whose value is not used or needed. The program behaves as if it was a verbatim compilation even though the compiler did otherwise. I think that is what the quoted passage is referring to, but I need to see it in a few pages of context to be sure.

I think it's the volatile variables, as you suspect.

A lot depends on which version of C you are talking about.  In the C99 standard, section 5.1.2.3 says:

Accessing a volatile object, modifying an object, modifying a file, or calling a function
that does any of those operations are all side effects, which are changes in the state of
the execution environment.

In C2X drafts this becomes:

An access to an object through the use of an lvalue of volatile-qualified type is a volatile access. A
volatile access to an object, modifying a file, or calling a function that does any of those operations are all side effects, which are changes in the state of the execution environment.

So there's a big change here, with (non-volatile) modifications of objects no longer being part of the state of the execution environment (which is what I believe Modern C is talking about when it says "Observable state").
In a more general sense, "observable state" is just that which may be observed by anyone outside the program looking at it.  As such, any C implementation that wants to support something like memory-mapped I/O (eg, anything POSIX-like) is going to continue to need to treat all modifications of objects that might be memory mapped as part of the "observable state" regardless of whether they are volatile or not. This means for all practical purposes, variables with external linkage are part of the "observable state".

This is pretty much directly referring to the C23 5.2.2.4 chapter program semantics, describing the "abstract machine". That whole chapter in the standard is pretty fuzzy.
The concept of side effects are what determines what the compiler may or may not optimize, and that term is specified as:

A volatile access to an object, modifying an object, modifying a file, or calling a function that does any of those operations are all side effects, which are changes in the state of the execution environment.

Objects meaning variables. So that's essentially what's meant with "variables and outputs". The standard mentions compiler optimizations in this part:

An actual implementation is not required to evaluate part of an expression if it can deduce that its value is not used and that no needed side effects are produced

For example the side effect of updating a variable can be optimized out if that variable isn't used anywhere from there on. But a volatile access can never be optimized out.
Observable behavior pretty much means that the compiler can optimize out most things if the program is still doing what the programmer intended.
For example if I have function void f (void) { int x = 1; } then the compiler is free to optimize away the whole function and any call to it, since it contains no "needed" side effects. Writing 1 to x is a side effect but since that variable immediately goes out of scope, that's not needed.
But if the function was void f (void) { x = 1; } where x is something at file scope, then suddenly the write to x can't get optimized out because other parts of the program might be using x.
The compiler may still optimize out the actual function call overhead though, and "inline" the function - replacing any call f(); with machine code doing x=1;.
Additionally this write to x need to be "sequenced" - executed in a certain order - in relation to other such needed side effects. Otherwise in the normal case, instruction reordering is an allowed optimization.  The write to x may still be reordered in relation to non-related parts of the program but not in relation to other needed side effects.

Re “C23 5.1.2.4”: There is no clause 5.1.2.4 in the C 2024 standard. (There was in drafts.) 5.1.2.4 in the final working draft, N3054, is not relevant; it is about multithreading and data races. A relevant clause in C 2024 is 5.2.2.4 (“Program semantics”). A relevant clause in N3054 is 5.1.2.3 (“Program execution”).

Re “The concept of side effects are what determines what the compiler may or may not optimize”: No, observable behavior determines what the compiler may or may not optimize. Side effects are part of the abstract model, not part of the binding to observable behavior. Anything in the abstract model may be optimized as long as the observable behavior remains unchanged.

Re “Objects meaning variables”: Objects means data storage whose contents can represent values. Dynamically allocated memory may contain objects, and those objects are not variables.

Re “Additionally this write to x need to be "sequenced" - executed in a certain order - in relation to other such needed side effects. Otherwise in the normal case, instruction reordering is an allowed optimization”: Sequencing is part of the specification of the abstract machine, not of observable behavior. Side effects in the actual implementation may be reordered regardless of sequencing provided the observable behavior remains unchanged. For example, x = 3; y = 4; sequences the former before the latter in the abstract machine, but a program may execute them in the reverse order.

@EricPostpischil Feel free to post your own answer instead of constantly breathing down the neck of others. The quoted normative part "An actual implementation is not required to evaluate part of an expression if it can deduce that its value is not used and that no needed side effects are produced" is obviously part of what determines what may or may not be optimized. This whole chapter "program semantics" as well as the whole standard document is what describes the abstract machine, which you can read in the very first sentence of this chapter.

Re “…  is obviously part of what determines what may or may not be optimized”: I did not say otherwise. I said “The concept of side effects are what determines what the compiler may or may not optimize” is incorrect. The part of the standard you quote does not say that side effects determine what may or may not be optimized. The determination is based on what is “needed,” which is an allusion to the rules about observable behavior that follow, and it could apply to value or side effects…

…  If an expression produces value X and side effect Y, whether the expression may or may not be omitted has nothing to do with whether X or Y is a value or a side effect or something else. It depends on whether omitting X or Y would change the observable behavior of the program. Saying the concept of side effects determines whether it may be omitted or not is incorrect.

Re “Feel free to post your own answer instead of constantly breathing down the neck of others”: Whether anybody posts any other answer or not is irrelevant ot the quality of this answer. It is important to rebut false information so that readers are not misled. This answer is incorrect on multiple points and would misinform readers. It should be corrected or deleted.

@EricPostpischil The only part that's incorrect is the chapter enumeration of C23 drafts vs the published ISO version. That part has been fixed. As for side effects, the needed part is essential as explained here https://stackoverflow.com/a/79060874/584518 as well as in the examples of this answer. Furthermore this whole chapter of the standard is incredible vague and largely open for interpretation. Some compilers are for example known to re-order volatile accesses across other side effects, which is arguably non-conforming behavior and yet they do so.

The primary part of the C standard that allows and governs optimization is this passage in C 2024 5.2.2.4:

The least requirements on a conforming implementation are:
— Volatile accesses to objects are evaluated strictly according to the rules of the abstract machine.
— At program termination, all data written into files shall be identical to the result that execution of the program according to the abstract semantics would have produced.
— The input and output dynamics of interactive devices shall take place as specified in 7.23.3. The intent of these requirements is that unbuffered or line-buffered output appear as soon as possible, to ensure that prompting messages appear prior to a program waiting for input.
This is the observable behavior of the program.

Note that this passage does not define observable state, and it would be problematic to define observable behavior in terms of state alone, as the behavior includes input/output dynamics, which are interactions with the environment outside the program, not just states or changes of state.
Jens Gustedt’s use of observable state appears to predate, and hence be separate from, its use in the C standard, as it appears in a 2021 edition of Modern C, before its first appearance in the official standard, in 2024. “Observable state” does not appear in the 1999 version of the standard, the 2007 n1256 draft, the N1570 draft of the 2011 standard, or the 2018 standard. It also does not appear in draft N2912, dated June 8, 2022, precluding the possibility that the 2021 Modern C took it from a committee draft of the standard unless it appeared in a prior draft and was removed.
“Observable state” appears in the official 2024 standard without definition and in a context (6.7.13.8, “Standard attributes for function types”) that uses “observable” to discuss ordering of operations in the abstract machine, not in direct relation to optimization and rules about observable behavior. So this use of “observable state” appears to be separate from the use of “observable behavior” and not directly related to optimization rules.
Based on the both the timing of Jens Gustedt’s use of “observable state” and the unrelated meaning in the 2024 standard, I conclude Gustedt’s use of the term is not related to the C standard’s use of the term.
Given this, the meaning of “observable state” in Modern C is specific to that work, not informed by the C standard. Unfortunately, even granting the book its own meaning for “observable state,” its statements about the optimization rules appear to be incorrect relative to the C standard. Consider this from the passage you quote on page 46 of the edition dated October 15, 2024:

For an optimization to be valid, it is only important that a C compiler produces an executable that reproduces the observable statesC. Observable states consist of the contents of some variables (and similar entities that we will see later) and the output as
they evolve during the execution of the program.

This does not match the C standard’s specification of observable behavior in two ways:

Regarding the “contents of some variables,” it is the volatile access to an object, not its contents, that is observable behavior. (And it is an object, not a variable, that is at issue. Some objects are not parts of variables.) This is a fundamental issue; a volatile access to an object is an interaction with the world outside the program.

The “output as they evolve during execution of the program” is not a correct description. Program output is part of observable behavior in two ways: Data written into files must be identical to what the abstract machine would have produced at program termination. How it evolves during execution is irrelevant, except to the extent it is part of the following issue. Input/output dynamics are part of observable behavior, and those do require certain output during program execution, but that does not apply to all output and it does involve input actions, which this passage in Modern C fails to mention.


Another issue in in this passage from page 45:

Not all operations and their resulting values are observable from within your program. They are observable only if they are stored in addressable memory or written to an output device.

Here the text uses “addressable” in italic as if it were defining the term, but no definition is present. This passage is not an accurate description of observable behavior as defined by the C standard. In the standard, accesses to volatile objects are part of observable behavior. The standard does not make any distinction based on whether memory is addressable or not.
In conclusion, Modern C is inaccurate in its description of the rules of observable behavior and optimization in the C standard, and you should not rely on it for this.
